# NFC - New Ntag21X

Tags: nfc

I'm attempting to start coding for the new NTAG21X due to be released by the end of the year.  There is very limited information available regarding the new tags.  Only released to partners :-(

I'm trying to figure out how to use:

- password protection on the tag.  Will this be a key stored in one of the sectors and how will you go about reading NDEF?  Do you pass the password to read?
- originality signature.  Will it be a sector as on Mifare where you write key and lock the page(s) to protect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTAG21x is (will be) a NFC Forum Type 2 Tag (T2T) device, like NTAG203 (hence the "2" in the names). You can expect accessing functionality will be similar to standard T2T (and MIFARE Ultralight) read/write commands (so no MIFARE Classic sectors). Reading of NDEF shall be according to the T2T spec, so no password required. Write protect could be possible (similar to MIFARE Ultralight C).